# Why is a new "[filename]Notes.bib" file being created?

Tags: bibtex, revtex

After fiddling with my tex installation for other reasons, now my bibliography is not working.

The file "bibnotesMWE.tex", has the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,showpacs,onecolumn,pra,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs, dsfont}

\begin{document}

%
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\bibliography{bibnotesMWE}


\end{document}
```

with bibnotesMWE.bib as:

```
@article{test,
    author = {Testy McTestface},
    title = {Test}
}
```

In Texmaker, when I clean and then run PDFLatex, then run BibTex, I get

```
The top-level auxiliary file: bibnotesMWE.aux I couldn't open database file bibnotesMWENotes.bib ---line 2 of file bibnotesMWE.aux...
```

It turns out some part of the compilation has produced an empty file called "bibnotesMWENotes.bib" (that is, it just appends "Notes" to the filename and adds a .bib extension), and bibnotesMWE.aux tries to open this and fails (line 2 is `\bibdata{bibnotesMWENotes,bibnotesMWE}`).

How do I make it stop creating this file and trying to access it, and use the bibliography file that I specify?

The problem might go deeper as well: If I manually set the line in "bibnotesMWE.aux" to `\bibdata{bibnotesMWE}`, it gives the same error, but with references to `bibnotesMWE.tex`. I tried adding the full filepath and it complained about whitespace; maybe there is a way to avoid the whitespace, but I have never needed to use full filepaths for bibliographies before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `<main .tex filename>Notes.bib` is created in order to support `revtex4-1`'s `footinbib` option that sends `\footnote`s to the bibliography. [The REVTeX 4.1 Author’s Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/revtex4-1/doc/latex/revtex/auguide/auguide4-1.pdf) has the following to say about footnotes (§ VII, p. 13)

> LaTeX’s standard `\footnote` command is available in REVTeX 4.1.
> The footnote text can either appear at the bottom of a page or as part of the bibliography.
> This choice can be controlled by two class options: `footinbib` and `nofootinbib`.
> REVTeX 4.1 defaults to the former.
> Specific journal options may select a different value than the default.
> Please note that even if BibTeX is not being used for the references, you may have to run BibTeX if you are using footnotes without the `nofootinbib` option.
> The log file will contain errors about missing references such as `Note1` in this case and a file ending in `Notes.bib` will have been produced during the processing of the TeX file.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,showpacs,onecolumn,pra,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{test,
  author = {Testy McTestface},
  title  = {Test},
  year   = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Lorem \footnote{ipsum} dolor \footnote{sit}.
Dolor \cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

generates a `...Notes.bib` containing

```
@FOOTNOTE{Note1,key="Note1",note="ipsum"}
@FOOTNOTE{Note2,key="Note2",note="sit"}
```

I was, howver, not able to reproduce the error you describe. In my tests `bibnotesMWENotes.bib` was always written even if it is empty. Note that the file can only be guaranteed to exists if the LaTeX run ended without errors.

If you also get an error about BibTeX not being able to find `bibnotesMWE.bib` when you manually remove the reference to `bibnotesMWENotes` in the `.aux` file, this looks like a completely different problem. Issues like this are very often caused by features called "'build' folder" or similar by editors or overly eager temporary file clean-ups or working directory mismatches.

Try running

```
pdflatex bibnotesMWE
bibtex bibnotesMWE
pdflatex bibnotesMWE
pdflatex bibnotesMWE
```

from the command line bypassing your editor and its possibly more complicated compilation setup.

Comment: Thanks, that's tells me about the bibnotes. The command line seemed to work fine, so it must be some texmaker problem. I think I messed up the distribution because a collaborator wants to use the rubber package, which uses a 2017 distribution, and I can't make revtex work without the 2020 distribution. So I "solved" the problem by moving the whole document to Overleaf.

Comment: @SamJaques You may want to check your TeXmaker build settings for something like "use a 'build' folder" or "hide auxiliary/temporary files in separate directory". This could be an issue here. If the command line invocations work this is definitely an issue with the TeXmaker settings.

Comment: Okay this is an old question but I was wondering whether you knew of a way to keep the "use a build folder" option whilst fixing this issue? Like can I "point" revtex to the right folder or something??? Thanks if you can help

Comment: @P.Lord Sorry, off the top of my head I don't have a solution. 'build' folders are a nightmare if you use more complex setups with additional auxiliary files and tools that need to read or write additional files. There might be ad hoc ways to tell the involved tools to look for the right file, but really my advice is to accept that you might get a few auxiliary files and not use a 'build' subdirectory. If you absolutely need a build subdirectory, ask a new question and explain your 'build' folder setup as detailed as possible.